# I have to do reload to check the changes done in flutter provider

Tags: flutter

I am creating an expense app where I want to show category details

if I add a transaction, category details should be updated based on transaction category.

here I have used random for a testing, will finish it later as soon as It is solved

here after adding record I have to reload and than I can see changes in category details...

my provider class

```
class SqfliteProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get getdatabase async {
    _database = await openDatabase(
        join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'expensedb34.db'),
        version: 1, onCreate: (db, version) {
      db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE categorytb(title TEXT NOT NULL,entries INTEGER NOT NULL,totalamount STRING NOT NULL)");

      db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE expensetb(id TEXT NOT NULL,title TEXT NOT NULL,amount STRING NOT NULL,category STRING NOT NULL,date STRING NOT NULL)");

      //add some default categories
      for (int x = 0; x < icons.length; x++) {
        db.insert('categorytb', {
          'title': icons.keys.toList()[x],
          'entries': 0,
          'totalamount': (0.0).toString()
        });
      }
    });
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<List<CategoryModel>?> fetchcategory() async {
    final db = await getdatabase;

    List<CategoryModel> templist = [];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist = await db.query('categorytb');

    if (maplist.isEmpty) return null;
    templist = maplist.map((e) => CategoryModel.frommap(e)).toList();
    return templist;

  }



  Future<void> addTransaction(TransactionModel transactionModel) async {
    final db = await getdatabase;

    //insert in database
    await db.insert('expensetb', transactionModel.tomap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);


    notifyListeners();
    await db.update('categorytb', {
      'entries':Random().nextInt(500)
    },where: 'title==?',whereArgs:['Travel']).then((value) => print('Updated'));
    notifyListeners();




    //update category information
  }
}
```

and this is widget that display category table detail

```
class CategoryFetcher extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final provider=Provider.of<SqfliteProvider>(context,listen: false);
    return  FutureBuilder(
      future: provider.fetchcategory(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<CategoryModel>?>snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: WaitWidget());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return   ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    CategoryModel t = snapshot.data![index];
                    return CategoryCard(categorymodel: t);
                  });

            
          } else {
            return Text('Something wrong');
          }
        } else {
          return Text('Last if');
        }

      },
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

It was my mistake

wrong

```
 final provider=Provider.of<SqfliteProvider>(context,listen: false);
```

right

```
 final provider=Provider.of<SqfliteProvider>(context,listen: true);
```